# Не запускается индексация Sphinx на ubuntu 18

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, sphinx, sphinxsearch

Сервер VPS: Ubuntu 18.04, LAMP, Nginx, файрвол выключен.
Установил Sphinx, с горем пополам настроил индексацию одной БД, все нормально (проиндексировалась), потом переделал для новой БД (старая оказалась не нужна, и ее индекс, соответственно, тоже).

Настроил конфиг сфинкса:

```
source table_sourse
{
    # Тип данных (mysql, pgsql, mssql, xmlpipe, xmlpipe2, odbc)
    type            = mysql

    # Необходимые параметры для подключения к базе данных
    sql_host      = localhost
    sql_user      = User
    sql_pass      = Pass
    sql_db        = table
    sql_port      = 3306

    # пред-запрос, выполняется перед выполнением основного запроса на получение данных из базы (кодировка UTF-8)
    sql_query_pre       = SET NAMES utf8

    # запрос, который получает данные документов для поиска (первое поле обязательно уникальный положительный ID документа)
    sql_query = SELECT code, name, nds, posh FROM table 

    sql_attr_bigint = code
    sql_attr_string = name
}


# индекс для поиска
index table
{
     # Источник данных (таблица в БД) для индексирования
    source            = table

    # Адрес, где будут хранится данные индекса
    path            = /home/user/data

    # Индекс с учетом морфологии
    morphology        = stem_ru

    # Минимальная длина слова для индексации
    min_word_len        = 1

    # Кодировка
    charset_type        = utf-8

    # Так и не понял, что это, поэтому закомментировал
    # docinfo           = extern
}

indexer 
{
    mem_limit = 1024M # лимит памяти для работы индексатора 
}


# Поисковая служба
searchd
{
    # какой порт и какой протокол "слушает" служба  
    listen            = 9306:mysql41

    # файл с логами
    log               = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log

    # файл с логами поисковых запросов
    query_log         = /var/log/sphinxsearch/query.log

    read_timeout      = 60
    max_children      = 30

    # PID file, searchd process ID file name
    pid_file          = /var/run/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid

    seamless_rotate   = 0
    preopen_indexes   = 1
    unlink_old        = 1
    binlog_path       = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data
}
```

Перезагрузил сервер. Вошел как root, запускаю Сфинкс командой:

```
searchd
```

Получаю ошибку (ниже скрин). Проверяю запущенные процессы, сфинкса там нет.
Пробую запустить индексацию:

```
sudo indexer --all
```

Тоже ошибка (скрин с двумя командами). Ругается на файл конфига
[image: Скрин с ошибкой, рядом файл конфига с номерами строк]

До этого рекомендовали мне удалить PID файл (сделал, но могу восстановить) и старый индекс. Все сделал, но мало что изменилось.

После исправлений, при индексации такое:
[image: Скриншот с ошибкой]

Будто бы он выплонил эту индексацию, но файлов индекса в папке /var/lib/sphinxsearch/
нет (вообще никаких файлов нет).

Да, еще уточнение: в этой БД столбцом с уникальным номером сроки является столбец name. Сфинкс на него тоже ругается (см. второй скрин)

В чем заключается ошибка, и как ее исправить?

Comment: Приложите проблемный конфиг текстом (тот конфиг, что приложен сейчас, явно отличается от конфига на скриншоте) (я, разумеется, не про пароли, если что:)

Comment: А если `sql_query` в строку записать без слешей ?

Comment: searchd запускал, просто на скрине не видно. Сначала думал, что индексацию надо делать с выключенным Сфинксом, а оказывается, надо с включенным?
Запрос писал и в строку без слешей, не менялось ничего

Первый косяк нашел: два раза повторялась строка  type = mysql
Второй косяк - в таблице отсутствует столбец с уникальным id и в запросе нет обращения к нему. В другой таблице, которая индексировалась, он был. 

Как правильно сделать SQL запрос, чтобы добавить в начало таблицы столбец с id, который автоматически проставит значения и будет добавлять их сам, по мере добавления значений?

Comment: Новый скрин и исправленный конфиг добавил

Comment: Каталог `/var/lib/sphinxsearch/data` вообще существует?

Comment: Да, каталог /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data существует

Answer (score 0):

На скриншоте не видно запуска searchd. Видна только попытка остановки (searchd --stop). Попробуйте просто searchd (без --stop).

--rotate в  indexer имеет смысл только при уже работающем searchd. Впрочем в данном случае бы тоже сработало, если б вы после indexer --rotate выполнили просто searchd, а не searchd --stop.

Comment: searchd запускал, просто на скрине не видно. Сначала думал, что индексацию надо делать с выключенным Сфинксом, а оказывается, надо с включенным?

Comment: C влюченным searchd нельзя делать indexer без --rotate. С выключенным можно и так и так, просто --rotate не сработает, если searchd не запущен, но индексация пройдет. По поводу ошибки про бинлог:  убедитесь, что у пользователей, под которыми запускаете indexer и searсhd есть доступ до директории и файла, на которые ругается indexer. Если нет директории - создайте. Если хочется хранить бинлог в другом месте - пропишите другую директорию в binlog_path в секции searchd конфига.

Comment: Спасибо за инфу про rotate
Остальное уже выправил, все равно ничего не работает.
Пишу же, что заходу под рутом, разве у рута может быть, что нет прав?